# Javascript - Search and highlight words in a text (mixed or in a row)

Tags: javascript, string, button, search

I am trying to find a javascript code for a word searcher in a text (through a form and a search button). Ι have found one which can search many words at the same time, but they need to be in a row. If the words are mixed it doesn't work. What kind of updates should we make?

Please advise

My regards

my code

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <title>Word finder</title>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Text Finder</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
}
body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 320px;
  height: 50vh;
}
input#keyword {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #0f62fe;
  width: auto;
}
span.highlight {
  color: black; background-color:yellow;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px red;
}
</style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <p>English texts for beginners to practice reading and comprehension online and for free. Practicing your comprehension 
of written English will both improve your vocabulary and understanding of grammar and word order. The texts below are designed 
to help you develop while giving you an instant evaluation of your progress.</p>
    </div>
    <h1>Find the word in paragraph</h1>

    <div class="form">
      <input type="text" id="keyword" class="form_control" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>

    <script>
      function textFind(keyword) {
        if(keyword) {
          var content = $("p").text();
          var searchText = new RegExp(keyword, "ig");
          var matches = content.match(searchText);       

          if(matches) {
            $("p").html(content.replace(searchText, function(match){
              return "<span class='highlight'>"+match+"</span>";
            }));
          }else {
            $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
          }
        }else{
          $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        }
      }
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#keyword').on('keyup', function(){
          textFind($(this).val());
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

To search many words mixed

Answer (score 0):

As I don't exactly know what methods you would like to use. I can't fully answer.

But take a look at this js method: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp